# CSS on button, causing problems in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, button

I'm slowly, but steady, getting more and more frustrated.

I have a 'Coming Soon'-page on http://badeanstalten.com/. If I click the button in Firefox, the button gets half white and half the original color/state. I need to get rid of the white, annoying thingy.

The problem isn't there with Chrome & Safari. What to do?

Comment: Please don't use URL shorteners in posts on Stackoverflow. There's no reason to not post the actual URL of your site

Answer (score 2):

You have several rules for `.btn:focus` on bootstrap.min.css (line 9) that cause this effect

Comment: ... and? An answer that presented a _solution_ would help

Comment: The rule that causes the problem is `background-position:0 -15px;` for `.btn:hover,.btn:focus`

Comment: @Bojangles if I say "why is this red? how can i solve this?" and someone points out that "look, there, it says color: red", then is that not answer enough?

Comment: The OP doesn't want to know what the cause is, they want to be shown how to _fix the problem_

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure but you should give it a try.
Add the following class to your CSS.

```
.btn-custom:focus {
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}
```

It will override the default `.btn:focus` bootstrap class which is the one changing the background colour.